# Forms on partial doesn't render properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I have a Rails app that is running fine on Rails 3.x and ActiveAdmin 0.6.6. However I want to upgrade it to Rails 5 and ActiveAdmin 1.x. I started the upgrade process first upgrading from 3.x to 4.x and then to 5x, and with ActiveAdmin I tested with 1.0.0 and now I'm using the master from Github.

Everything worked fine with the App in both Rails versions and ActiveAdmin but the ActiveAdmin forms that are in a partial.

The problem is the following:

I have a file `app/admin/menu.rb` whose has a partial `views/admin/menus/_form.html.erb`. 
The partial contains the form of the Menu.

This is the contents of the partial (`views/admin/menus/_form.html.erb`):

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @menu], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f| %>
  <% f.inputs 'Campos Menu' do %>
    <% f.input :project if current_admin_user.admin? %>
    <% f.input :title %>
    <% f.input :title_en %>
    <% f.input :item %>
    <% f.input :icon, as: :file %>
  <% end %>
  <% f.inputs 'Submenus' do %>
    <% f.has_many :submenus, heading: '' do |fa| %>
      <% fa.input :title, as: :string %>
      <% fa.input :title_en, as: :string %>
      <% fa.input :kind, as: :select, collection: Submenu.kind_collection %>
      <% fa.input :items_as, as: :select, collection: Submenu.items_as_collection %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% f.actions do %>
    <% f.action :submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The render result of this file is only the 'actions' buttons, in this case the 'submit' button. The interesting thing is that if I remove the `<% f.actions do %>...` from the partial then the `<% f.inputs 'Submenus' do %>` gets rendered and the same if I remove the later. In other others is being rendered on the last block that contains an `end`.

The same behaviour is being observed on Rails 4.x and 5.x (except Rails 5.1.x which I didn't tested).

If I move the form from the partial to the `app/admin/menu.rb` it gets rendered properly. This could be a solution for me however I have others forms that make use of JQuery for fields manipulation and other stuff on the front end.

As I said before, all these forms partials were working properly on Rails 3.x and ActiveAdmin 0.6.6.

Anyone knows what's the problem?

DISCLAIMER: I'm not a Rails or ActiveAdmin expert, so bear with me if is a silly mistake related to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found was to put a `=` for the `<% f.input(s) %>` on the partial. Having something like this `<%= f.inputs ... %>` instead of this `<% f.inputs ... %>` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's [activeadmin#3486](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/3486)  I'm glad you figured out the workaround. I'm curious if [this Arbre branch](https://github.com/varyonic/arbre/commits/46_rails_tag_helper_with_block_in_arbre_template) fixes it for you.  Glad to see people still upgrading, I'll do what I can to help.

Comment: Hi, what would be the way to test this suggested branch in my project? How do I specify it on my GemFile. Anyway, I found a solution for my issue but I'm not sure if it the expected way to use the forms component, so what I did that worked was to put an ```=``` to most of the ```f.``` declaration, i.e. ```<%= f.inputs :name => 'Campos Menu' do %>```. Seems that the missing ```=``` was preventing the form to render properly. Do you know if this is a proper solution or this will lead to other issues?

Comment: `gem 'arbre', git: 'https://github.com/varyonic/arbre.git', branch: '46_rails_tag_helper_with_block_in_arbre_template'`

Comment: Personally I recommend going with the flow and using .arb partials instead of .erb with `active_admin_form_for resource do |f| ...`

Comment: I will give a shot to the abre gem. But migrate all my partials to abre is a bit more complicated. Let’s see! Thanks for the support.